# Windows phone 8.1 : display key from Dictionary<string,string> in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Below is my json

```
{"Hello":[{"CompanyName":"one","ETA":"10","Invoice":{"TF1":" 49","BF1":" 49","MD1":"2 Km","FPk1":" 12","att":"1 mins"},"tf3":"49"},{"CompanyName":"one","ETA":"10","Invoice":{"TF1":" 49","BF1":" 49","MD1":"2 Km","FPk1":" 15","att":"1 mins"},"tf3":"49"}],"ChildPresent":true}
```

I am deserialising everything and my main problem is with Invoice object ( `"Invoice":{"TF1":" 49","BF1":" 49","MD1":"2 Km","FPk1":" 15","att":"1 mins"},"tf3":"49"}]` ) which contains bunch of keys and values...the problem is with the keys inside "Invoice" object which changes after every 6 hours...And i need to display both keys and values in xaml

right now i am deserialising the above json everything into Modal and i am storing Invoice object data into Dictionary

```
RootObject j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

public class Hello {
    public Dictionary<string, string> Invoice { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName {get;set;}
    public string ETA {get;set;}
}
```

When i write in XAML`{Binding Invoice[TF1]}`
i get the value of TF1 but i want the key TF1 to be displayed in the XAML.

Comment: i have deserialized json and json values are getting stored in dictionary..
what exactly you want

Comment: public class Taxi
    {

      public Dictionary<string, string> Invoice { get; set; }
        
        public string yes { get; set;}        
        public string ETA { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Lat { get; set; }
        public string Lng { get; set; }
        }

Comment: Your problem is that you're trying to bind to a Dictionary<K,V>.  Dictionaries SUCK when it comes to binding.  Bindings see them as IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,V>>.  It's a big old mess of crap.  Stay far away from it as much as possible.

Comment: IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,V>> given an json deserialisation error

Comment: What is even the point of doing this? If you need one entry from a dictionary, just retrieve that in your code instead of binding to it. Bind to a property that retrieves the value e.g. `public string RelevantInvoice {get { return Invoice[FirstName]; } }` or something like that.

Comment: I want keyname to be displayed on the xaml textblock

Comment: What do you mean by "keyname"? Your key is `FirstName`. Why would you bind to `Invoice[FirstName]` if you want to display `FirstName`?

Comment: No.....i want to display only Keyname

Comment: Lemme repeat myself: WHAT DO YOU MEAN BY "keyname"?

Comment: {keyname:value}

Right i am getting value if i use Binding[Keyname] but i want to display keyname in xaml

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is `{Binding Path=Invoice.Key}`. Since this doesn't work, make sure you have set the correct DataContext at the top of your Page. The header should look like:

```
<Page
    ...
    DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    ...>
```

This means that the XAML will look for the Dictionary in the code-behind file it is attached to (i.e. if your XAML file is `Page.xaml`, then the code-behind file is `Page.xaml.cs`). If you don't specify this, then it has no idea where to look for `Invoice`.

---

(**NOTE:** Since you're developing for Windows Phone 8.1, if you go to Visual Studio and create a Hub App template project for Windows Phone, it should demonstrate how to bind to a Dictionary from XAML.)

Comment: I have already binded Viewmodel to the listview and since i am getting the value of the key by using {Binding Path=Invoice[FirstName]}

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Key` property off of a `Dictionary<,>`. There is a `Keys` property but one cannot index into it using a named value.

> keyname to displayed in xaml

This makes no sense...`Name` of the key? Or the value of the *key* from a literal `Name` as the key?

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Invoice[Name]}" />
```

or literal text.

```
 <TextBlock Text="Name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying Path=:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Invoice}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}"></TextBlock>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: use  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ExchangesDictionary[Invoice].Name}" />